# Javascript call method in caller's context

Tags: javascript, scope

How would I call a method in instanced object, but in context of another 
instanced object.

Best way to explain is with this brief expamle..

game.js

```
var ball = new Ball();
ball.addMotionListener(function(){this.color = someNewRandomColor});
```

inside ball.js

```
Ball = class{
  constructor(){
    this._position = new Vector(0,0);
    this._color = red;
    this._onChangeManager = new OnChangeManager();
  }

  addMotionListener(listener){
    this._onChnangeManager.addMotionListner(listener);
  }

  set position(newP){ 
    this._position = newP; 
    this._onChangeManager.motionEvent();
  }

}
```

and in onChangeManager.js

```
OnChangeManager = class{
  constructor{ this._motionListenerQueue = [] }

  addMotionListener(newListener){
    this._motionListenerQueue.push(newListener);
  }

  motionEvent(){
    for(listener in _motionListenerQueue){
      listener();
    }
  }
}
```

Now in game.js

```
kickBall(ball);
```

which changes ball position, triggers motion event listener in onChangeManager, with goal of changing balls color. Ofcourse this doesn't work, since `this.color` is in ball's context and not in onChangeManager's.

Is it possible to run method in onChangeManager object, but in ball's context?

Edit: Sorry for trivial/duplicate question, I am not familiar with js contexts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You can use `call()` and something like: `this._onChnangeManager.addMotionListner.call(this, listener);` to set this for the function call.

Comment: too-long names like `_onChnangeManager` are good places for typos to hide

Comment: so every object that can interact with the "changeManager" needs its own `addMotionListener` method?

Comment: `for(listener in _motionListenerQueue){ listener() }` check out the difference between [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). you want the latter here

Comment: @Thomas Hey, that was just pseudocode, I wasn't careful with syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the context to the function that is being passed as a callback using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
var ball = new Ball();
ball.addMotionListener(function() {
    this.color = someNewRandomColor
}.bind(ball));
```

P.S. In the callback you are referring to `color` property, while in `Ball` constructor there is `_color` property. I'm not sure if this difference is intended.

Comment: Is it possible to set whole onChangeManager to be bound to ball on `new OnChangeListener` ? Im sure your solution would work, but would take me whole day to fix in my project :s

Comment: Well, you can pass the `Ball` instance in `OnChangeManager` like: 
`this._onChangeManager = new OnChangeManager(this);` 
and then in `OnChangeManager` constructor assign it to a property, let's say `this.ball`.
 Then in `for` loop you can invoke each listener using `Function.prototype.call` with `this.ball` as a context: `listener.call(this.ball)`;

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I needed, Thanks :)

Comment: @Jonzi My pleasure :)